# I'm getting errors that leaves two of my database tables empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I've been getting an error "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::$id " on my php Laravel code when I run the command php artisan db:seed. Although not all tables I've created are affected, 2 of them remain empty with no data to be shown in them. Here's the code that I've written for them.

```
namespace Database\Factories;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Category;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
 protected $model = Product::class;

 public function definition()
{
return [
    "title"=>$this->faker->sentence,
    "slug"=>Str::slug($this->faker->sentence),
    "description"=>$this->faker->paragraph,
    "price"=>$this->faker->numberBetween($min=100,$max=900),
    "old_price"=>$this->faker->numberBetween($min=100,$max=900),
    "inStock"=>$this->faker->numberBetween($min=1,$height=10),
    "image"=>$this->faker->imageUrl($width=640,$height=480),
    "category_id"=>factory(Category::class)->id,
    ];
}
}
```

The error highlights the last line of my code ""category_id"=>factory(Category::class)->id,"

Here's is the code that's supposed to populate the 2nd table called "Order Factory"
Order Factory
<?php

```
  namespace Database\Factories;
  use App\Models\User;
  use App\Models\Order;
  use Faker\Generator as Faker;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
  use Illuminate\Support\Str;


  class OrderFactory extends Factory
 {
   protected $model = Order::class;

   public function definition()
 {
    return [
        
     "user_id"=>factory(User::class)->id,
     "product_name"=>$this->faker->word,
     "qty"=>$this->faker->numberBetween($min=1,$height=10),
     "price"=>$this->faker->numberBetween($min=100,$max=900),
     "total"=>$this->faker->numberBetween($min=1000,$max=9000),
    ];
}
}
```

Yesterday, an error was appearing at the line ""user_id"=>factory(User::class)->id" until when I added the "->id" line in my code, then the error wasn't showing anymore. I'm using the  faker model to try and populate the fake users inside my db. If anyone has any knowledge why this error is showing up when I run the code and has any expertise in laravel8, help me fix this error so I can seed data into my db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're calling the factories wrong.

```
"user_id"=>factory(User::class)->id,
```

Should be

```
"user_id"=> User::factory()->create()->id,
```

Only if you create the entity you can access its ID.

Be aware: It's the same in your product factory.

More details described in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#instantiating-models